# Retrieving image from Fire Storage however if the image does not exist the app crashes

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi I recently figured out how to upload and image to Firebase Storage using the UIImagePickerController and also how to display that image inside a UIImageView on my View Controller, however the problem is that if the file does not already exist in Fire Storage then the app crashes before I even get a chance to upload an image.  I am new to this so I am hoping someone has a simple fix to my code on how I am retrieving the image.  I would like to retrieve the image from Fire. Storage but if that image doesn't exist yet then it doesn't crash the app but simply over looks it. Here is the code I am using to retrieve the image that works but only if the image already exist.  Thanks for any help!

The error I get is unexpectedly found Nil when unwrapping Optional Value

//Retrieves uploaded photo from Firestorage using Firestore Database-Current User- that is Logged in and displays Image to UIImageView in ViewController called profileimage.image

```swift
func downloadimages() {
    let reference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\("images/"+Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid+"+.jpg")")
    reference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        self.profileimage.image = image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the solution out to this issue as well and wanted to post in case any new coders have the same problem.  I simply had to add

```
if error != nil {
  print(error!.localizedDescription)
  return
}
```

Full Example

```
func downloadimages() {
    let reference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\("images/"+Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid+"+.jpg")")
    reference.downloadURL{(url, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        self.profileimage.image = image
    }
}
```